# OmniPCX XML Framework

Tags: xml, soap

We have omnipcx phone systems all over the company, I am wanting to write something to download the phone listing off them.

Alcatel's API documents have been less than helpful. The problem I have is that I need to be able to consume a soap web service on the pbx but I just get 503 http errors back. The alcatel management app communicates on tcp:443 (I cant see the http header since it is hidden within ssl). The API documentation for the XMLFwManagement Web Service gives me a url for the service that gives a 503 error too.

So I guess I am after someone out there who has had some experience here, I need to find the correct uri for the service (i guess) and I also guess my soap message is not correct.

my request looks like this atm.

```
GET /api/services/5.0/XMLApiFramework HTTP/1.1
Host: hostname
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 390

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<soap:Envelope encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding" xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope">
  <soap:Body>
    <m:login xmlns:m="http://hostname/api/services/5.0/XMLApiFramework">
      <m:pFwUser>AzureDiamond</m:pFwUser>
      <m:pFwPass>hunter2</m:pFwPass>
    </m:login>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Hi Matthew. I have exactly the same problem at the moment. Your message and url looks fine for me. Have you seen a solution meanwhile?

Comment: I abandoned the project. The intent was to write an app to create a telephone directory from the alcatel api.